# Power grid dynamics: Does increased power use = increased fossil fuel use in grid?

Tags: power-grid

Say I come home on a hot day and crank my AC full blast (colder.) The grid is powered by wind, solar, hydro, coal, and natural gas. The additional power required by my cranking up the AC cannot be offset by wind, solar, or hydro, because they are always maximized, correct?

My additional power use must be offset by an increase in natural gas, correct? Or, at a basic level, any additional increase in my power use increases the amount of fossil fuels being used, but does not affect wind, solar, or hydro generated?

If this is too small a perturbation, say 1k or 10k homes crank their AC, does this increase only fossil fuel use, or is some offset by green energy?

Comment: your first premise is incorrect ... the rest of depend on the first one being correct

Comment: They will try to use as much wind and solar energy as possible because it's *free*. As much as possible might not be 100%. Hydro is free but can be stored so they might try to balance hydro now with hydro later.

Comment: @jsotola, could you elaborate on why the first premise is incorrect?

Comment: Solar can be curtailed and controlled. Newer grid-tie inverters respond to frequency changes (very small frequency changes) by scaling power. So it is not right to assume it is always maximized. BUT, if you come home from work on a hot day and crank the AC, at the same time everyone else is doing that, practically, in 2022, solar will be maximized at that time and all your assumptions are true.

Comment: https://www.enerdynamics.com/Energy-Currents_Blog/The-Duck-Curve-Becomes-Extreme-in-California.aspx

Comment: The main effects of adding solar to the grid in California have been to push base load down (thus making baseload generation un-economical) and increase the need for peakers in the afternoons and evenings. This has been understood for at least a decade. But the utility companies have not really done much to address it, and the proponents of solar have pretended like it is not happening. They still compare directly the cost of solar generation to that of nuclear, for example, without any acknowledgement that they have different availability profiles.

Comment: @user253751 There is hydro power that may be stored if there is some space in damned lake left. But there is also hydro power where the water of the river should flow continuously without any possibility to store water.

Comment: @RayJ  ... `always maximized` cannot possibly be true

Comment: Thanks, @mkeith. Exactly what I was looking for. Good overview. Never heard of a duck curve before.

Answer (score 2):

You could be burning more dead dinos when you crank up your AC.

Some countries have populations and hence electrical loading that has far outstripped their hydro resources.  Wind and solar are helpful in the generation mix but they are not always available.  Hydro has high availability.  Nuclear has cost and safety concerns.

Thermal power plants in a well designed power grid are designed to be only used occasionally when demand exceeds supply from the other sources. Fossil fuels have been expensive since the 1970s and now there are carbon tax issues. So it depends on where you live.